# Can I access the text of my SMS messages using the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone

Can  I access the text of my SMS messages using the iPhone SDK?
Meaning existing messages, not creating new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, you cannot access these on a standard, non-jailbroken iPhone. You should file a bug with Apple, perhaps they'll improve SMS access in the future.

Comment: I doubt they would change this because it would be a privacy concern. If it was possible, I could write an app that reads a persons entire conversation. There
are few use cases where this would actually
be beneficial, so adding a safe guard wouldn't be worth their effort.

Comment: I agree, but they do provide access to the Address Book. Can't hurt to ask!