# Making Ip calls

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I access the text of my SMS messages using the iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488679/can-i-access-the-text-of-my-sms-messages-using-the-iphone-sdk)

**EDITED QUESTION**
I am really new to Ios environment, and I wanted to know if there is a way to make ip calls or something like skype.

Till now i understood how to make voice calls. But I want to stream live data. can any one give me any kind of lead?

Comment: You are welcome on StackOverflow but please be aware of methodologies how this community works. Please read [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before asking a question.

Comment: its not possible to fetch the call or sms history in iOS device..but it is possible to send email [check for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822031/call-history-sms-history-email-history-in-ios)

Comment: yes, I have seen that but that is 3 years old now.

Comment: So what difference does it make? You should check Apple documents and put some efforts before asking a question.

Comment: Voting to close as "Not a real question" because you are asking three different questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a text or an email message from your app, but you can't access existing ones. The reason for that limitation is security (so a malicious app can't steal your personal information/passwords/etc from your mailbox). See [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SystemMessaging_TopicsForIOS/Articles/SendinganSMSMessage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010416-SW1) for details.

You can also make a call by opening a special URL within your app. See, for example, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323171/making-a-phone-call-in-an-ios-application). Note that this will open the system phone app. You still can't access the call history though, for the same reasons I already mentioned

Comment: what about calls? I wanted to know the limitations of a developer.

Comment: You can make a call by opening a special URL within your app. See, for example, this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323171/making-a-phone-call-in-an-ios-application. Note that this will open the system phone app. You still can't access the call history though, for the same reasons I already mentioned.

Comment: Also, you can have tappable phone number hyperlinks in your app, e.g. in a UILabel or UITextArea.

Comment: Thanks i finally implemented this as you had suggested !!